# Reason for timeout?

Tags: z3

I'm new to using Z3. But I want to understand, the reason for time out in the following program inputted to Z3:

```
(declare-fun ADDR (Int) Int)
(declare-fun STAR (Int Int) Int)
(declare-fun VAR (Int Int) Int)
(declare-const error Int)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (= x (STAR (ADDR x) 0))) );causes a timeout?
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (>= (ADDR x) 4000)) )
(assert (not (= (VAR  error 0) 1)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Another question I have is, Is there something new with forall in version 3.2? I had to put the extra brackets around (x Int), else it were throwing an error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This formula is satisfiable, and Z3 fails to build a model for it.
You can avoid the timeout if you disable the model finder for quantified formulas.

```
(set-option :auto-config false)
(set-option :mbqi false)
```

If you do that, Z3 will return unknown and a "candidate model". This issue is discussed in the [Z3 guide](http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide).

The extra parenthesis is needed because Z3 3.x is fully compatible with the [SMT 2.0 standard](http://goedel.cs.uiowa.edu/smtlib/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.0-r10.12.21.pdf).

Comment: Are there any other options that I need to set differently from the default values in Z3 3.2 to get it to run like Z3 2.8?

Comment: Keep in mind that is not possible to simulate the exact behavior of Z3 2.8. Many changes (new algorithms, new features, algorithms, etc) were made since Z3 2.8. Are you observing a big performance discrepancy in your benchmarks?

Comment: Yeah. At the moment its hard to understand where the performance bottleneck is occuring. But a slowdown of 2x or more is seen in the output.
I wish to prevent possibilities wherein the new version of Z3 tries to solve, while the old one just gives up saying "unknown". For eg: as in the case of MBQI = false.
I'm just trying to understand if there are other INI parameters that must be changed from default values in the new Z3 to provide behavior as close to 2.8 as possible.
Thanks.